# what is the fastest algorithm for permutations of three condition?

Tags: c, optimization, boolean, atmega

Can anybody help me regarding quickest method for evaluating three conditions in minimum steps?
I have three conditions and if any of the two comes out to be true,then whole expression becomes `true` else `false`.

I have tried two methods:

```
if ((condition1 && condition2) || 
    (condition1 && condition3) || 
    (condition2 && condition3))
```

Another way is to by introducing variable `i` and

```
i = 0;
if (condition1) i++;
if (condition2) i++;
if (condition3) i++;
if (i >= 2)
    //do something
```

I want any other effective method better than the above two.

I am working in a memory constrained environment (Atmeta8 with 8 KB of flash memory) and need a solution that works in C.

Comment: So are we sure this is C and not e.g. Java, C++, C# or some other C-like language which isn't actually C?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: yes, OP commented on the PHP answer.

Comment: @Wooble Ah, I see it now. OK then, move on. :)

Comment: Are the conditions boolean variables that have already been calculated, or are they yet to be evaluated expressions and you want to avoid evaluating them?

Comment: @jxh They are need to be calculated....

Comment: I know you need to know if 2 out of 3 are true. In your question, are `condition1`, `condition2` and `condition3` `int` variables? I ask, because they *look* like variables in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is always hard to give a just "better" solution (better in what regard -- lines of code, readability, execution speed, number of bytes of machine code instructions, ...?) but since you are asking about execution speed in this case, we can focus on that.

You can introduce that variable you suggest, and use it to reduce the conditions to a simple less-than condition once the answer is known. Less-than conditions trivially translate to two machine code instructions on most architectures (for example, `CMP` (compare) followed by `JL` (jump if less than) or `JNL` (jump if not less than) on Intel IA-32). With a little luck, the compiler will notice (or you can do it yourself, but I prefer the clarity that comes with having the same pattern everywhere) that `trues < 2` will *always* be true in the first two `if()` statements, and optimize it out.

```
int trues = 0;
if (trues < 2 && condition1) trues++;
if (trues < 2 && condition2) trues++;
if (trues < 2 && condition3) trues++;
// ...
if (trues >= 2)
{
    // do something
}
```

This, once an answer is known, reduces the possibly complex evaluation of `conditionN` to a simple less-than comparison, because of the boolean short-circuiting behavior of most languages.

Another possible variant, if your language allows you to cast a boolean condition to an integer, is to take advantage of that to reduce the number of source code lines. You will still be evaluating each condition, however.

```
if( (int)(condition1)
  + (int)(condition2)
  + (int)(condition3)
  >= 2)
{
    // do something
}
```

This works based on the assumption that casting a boolean FALSE value to an integer results in 0, and casting TRUE results in 1. You can also use the conditional operator for the same effect, although be aware that it may introduce additional branching.

```
if( ((condition1) ? 1 : 0)
  + ((condition2) ? 1 : 0)
  + ((condition3) ? 1 : 0)
  >= 2)
{
    // do something
}
```

Depending on how smart the compiler's optimzer is, it *may* be able to determine that once any two conditions have evaluated to true the entire condition will always evaluate to true, and optimize based on that.

- Note that **unless you have actually profiled your code and determined this to be the culprit**, this is likely a case of premature optimization. **Always strive for code to be readable by human programmers first**, and fast to execute by the computer second, unless you can show definitive proof that the *particular* piece of code you are looking at is an *actual* performance bottleneck. *Learn how that profiler works* and put it to good use. Keep in mind that in most cases, programmer time is an awful lot more expensive than CPU time, and clever techniques take longer for the maintenance programmer to parse.
- Also, compilers are really clever pieces of software; sometimes they will actually detect the *intent* of the code written and be able to use specific constructs meant to make those operations faster, but that relies on it being able to determine what you are trying to do. A perfect example of this is swapping two variables using an intermediary variable, which on IA-32 can be done using `XCHG` eliminating the intermediary variable, but the compiler has to be able to determine that you are actually doing that and not [something clever which may give another result in some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16033705/486504).
- Since the vast majority of the non-explicitly-throwaway software written spends the vast majority of its lifetime in maintenance mode (and lots of throwaway software written is alive and well long past its intended best before date), it makes sense to optimize for maintainability unless that comes at an unacceptable cost in other respects. Of course, if you are evaluating those conditions a trillion times inside a tight loop, targetted optimization very well might make sense. But the profiler will tell you exactly which portions of your code need to be scrutinized more closely from a performance point of view, meaning that you avoid complicating the code unnecessarily.

And the above caveats said, I have been working on code recently making changes that at first glance would almost certainly be considered premature detail optimization. If you have a requirement for high performance and use the profiler to determine which parts of the code are the bottlenecks, then the optimizations aren't premature. (They may still be ill-advised, however, depending on the exact circumstances.)

Comment: Respected @Michael what i meant from better is fast in execution
your second approach is worth appreciating thanks
but also as u have said that code should be human readable then it shouldnt because we are coding for machine not for human,instead comments are meant for us to understand code

Comment: It's pretty hard to optimize *both* for execution speed *and* memory usage. Either one is easy, but both at the same time is much harder; usually one picks one or the other, and optimizes for that at the expense of the other. Are you sure you can't find two bits somewhere to repurpose? (And are variables really kept in *flash* memory? In that case: ouch!)

Answer (score 9):

This can be reduced to:

```
if((condition1 && (condition2 || condition3)) || (condition2 && condition3))
    //do something
```

Depending on the likelihood of each condition, you may be able to optimize the ordering to get faster short-circuits (although this would probably be premature optimization...)

Comment: yeah @wooble better than mine two's

Comment: *"although this would probably be premature optimization."* - No, it wouldn't, since it doesn't cost any effort nor introduce any significant code change.

Comment: @ChristianRau: well, it takes the effort to figure out the statistical likelihood of each condition, which may or may not be trivial.

Comment: It's not just ordering by likelihood.  If one of the conditions is harder to evaluate then it should be moved to a position where it's more likely to be short-circuited.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on your language, I might resort to something like:

```
$cond = array(true, true, false);

if (count(array_filter($cond)) >= 2)
```

or

```
if (array_reduce($cond, function ($i, $k) { return $i + (int)$k; }) >= 2)
```

Comment: @shafeeq That kind of information really ought to go directly into the question, but it is good that it at least was explicitly mentioned somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

There is no absolut answer to this. This depends very much on the underlying architecture. E.g. if you program in VHDL or Verilog some hardware circuit, then for sure the first would give you the fastest result. I assume that your target some kind of CPU, but even here very much will depend on the target cpu, the instruction it supports, and which time they will take. Also you dont specify your target language (e.g. your first approach can be short circuited which can heavily impact speed).

If knowing nothing else I would recommend the second solution - just for the reason that your intentions (at least 2 conditions should be true) are better reflected in the code.

The speed difference of the two solutions would be not very high - if this is just some logic and not the part of some innermost loop that is executed many many many times, I would even guess for premature optimization and try to optimize somewhere else.

Comment: Actually this is code for Atmega8,and this is in inner loop.so considering speed factor first approach is better.Is this??

Answer (score 1):

You may consider simpy adding them. If you use masroses from standart `stdbool.h`, then `true` is 1 and `(condition1 + condition2 + condition3) >= 2` is what you want.

But it is still a mere microoptimization, usually you wouldn't get a lot of productivity with this kind of tricks.

Comment: Note that this is pretty much exactly (minus the explicit cast) one of the techniques I suggested in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17216116/486504).

Answer (score 1):

Since we're not on a deeply pipelined architecture there's probably no value in branch avoidance, which would normally steer the optimisations offered by desktop developers.  Short-cuts are golden, here.

If you go for:

```
if ((condition1 && (condition2 || condition3)) || (condition2 && condition3))
```

then you probably have the best chance, without depending on any further information, of getting the best machine code out of the compiler.  It's possible, in assembly, to do things like have the second evaluation of `condition2` branch back to the first evaluation of `condition3` to reduce code size, but there's no reliable way to express this in C.

If you know that you will usually fail the test, and you know which two conditions usually cause that, then you might prefer to write:

```
if ((rare1 || rare2) && (common3 || (rare1 && rare2)))
```

but there's still a fairly good chance the compiler will completely rearrange that and use its own shortcut arrangement.

You might like to annotate things with `__builtin_expect()` or `_Rarely()` or whatever your compiler provides to indicate the likely outcome of a condition.

However, what's far more likely to meaningfully improve performance is recognising any common factors between the conditions or any way in which the conditions can be tested in a way that simplifies the overall test.

For example, if the tests are simple then in assembly you could almost certainly do some basic trickery with carry to accumulate the conditions quickly.  Porting that back to C is *sometimes* viable.

Answer (score 0):

You seem wiling to evaluate all the conditions, as you proposed such a solution yourself in your question. If the conditions are very complex formulas that take many CPU cycles to compute (like on the order of hundreds of milliseconds), then you  may consider evaluating all three conditions simultaneously with threads to get a speed-up. Something like:

```
pthread_create(&t1, detached, eval_condition1, &status);
pthread_create(&t2, detached, eval_condition2, &status);
pthread_create(&t3, detached, eval_condition3, &status);
pthread_mutex_lock(&status.lock);
while (status.trues < 2 && status.falses < 2) {
    pthread_cond_wait(&status.cond, &status.lock);
}
pthread_mutex_unlock(&status.lock);
if (status.trues > 1) {
    /* do something */
}
```

Whether this gives you a speed up depends on how expensive it is to compute the conditions. The compute time has to dominate the thread creation and synchronization overheads.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
unsigned char i;

i = condition1;
i += condition2;
i += condition3;
if (i & (unsigned char)0x02)
{
    /*
    At least 2 conditions are True
    0b00 - 0 conditions are true
    0b01 - 1 conditions are true
    0b11 - 3 conditions are true 
    0b10 - 2 conditions are true
    So, Checking 2nd LS bit is good enough.
    */
}
```

Comment: How does introducing an *additional* operation (the bitwise `and`) once all conditions have been evaluated help reduce the number of conditions that need to be evaluated? This technique is unlikely to eliminate the need for a comparison, so only adds code. The OP's problem is based around needing to evaluate all constituent conditions, not the time taken to find out whether at least two of them are true. Also, your example works *only* if that particular bit is set in the count; what if there are, say, five conditions involved? 5 (base 10) = 101 (base 2); 101 (base 2) & 2 (base 16) == 0. Fail.